# User class repository not found in the controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `User` Entity class and I craete a `UserRepository.php` in the same directory to put my custom methods in it, But when I use that in a contoller using this syntax it won't work:

my Repository:

```
namespace Doobin\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
public function pageAccess($User=1,$Page='_home')
{
    $stmt="Somthing to test";
    return $stmt;

}

}
```

My controller to use repository:

```
use Doobin\UserBundle\Entity\User;
.
.
.
.
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $products = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->pageAccess();
    var_dump($products);
```

When I use it, It counld't find the pageAccess method.

Should I introduce the repository somewhere? becuase the tuturial itself didn't say anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your User entity you should add annotation on the top of the class :

```
/**
 * User.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
}
```